# Java AWT troubleshooting

Tags: java, graphics, awt

So I've been trying to create a simple graphics program to run on Windows 10. From what I can infer, this is how my textbook would like me to create this program:

```
    import java.awt.*;
public class DrawLine1 {
    public static void main (String[]args) {
        DrawingPanel panel = new DrawingPanel(1281, 721);
        Graphics g = panel.getGraphics();
        g.drawLine(1, 1, 69, 69);
    }
}
```

However, when I try to compile it, cmd returns the following error:
D

```
rawLine1.java:4: error: cannot access DrawingPanel
                DrawingPanel panel = new DrawingPanel(1281, 721);
                ^
  bad source file: .\DrawingPanel.java
    file does not contain class DrawingPanel
    Please remove or make sure it appears in the correct subdirectory of the sourcepath.
1 error
```

Is this an error with the code I wrote or with how I set up Java, and how do I fix it?

Comment: I recommend looking at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/ .

Comment: *"From what I can infer, this is how my textbook would like me to create this program: .. `Graphics g = panel.getGraphics();`"* Either you have completely misunderstood the text book, or that book is worthless and should be used as a door stop / kindling.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like the code you've written is incomplete -- the compiler appears to be complaining that it can't find the DrawingPanel class, and if it doesn't exist, then you also need to create and compile the DrawingPanel code first. But having said that, I wouldn't recommend that you use this code or whatever tutorial suggests it as it's making some key bad recommendations

- For one, you need to display any drawing JPanel (assuming DrawingPanel **is** a JPanel) in a top level window for it to be displayed. For Swing GUI's this would mean you would need to create a JFrame and put the drawing JPanel into it, and then set the JFrame as visible via `setVisible(true)`
- Drawing with a components Graphics object in this way -- by calling `getGraphics()` is not recommended as the Graphics object obtained in this fashion is not guaranteed to persist. For instance, assuming that you get this code to work, if you minimized and restored your GUI, your line would disappear.
- Swing and AWT graphics are passive -- you would override your JPanel's paintComponent method and do your drawing inside of this method.
- You should start Swing and AWT GUI's on the Swing event thread. This is usually done by placing this code into a Runnable's `run()` method and then passing the Runnable into a `SwingUtilities.invokeLater(...)` method call.

For example:

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.*;

public class SimpleLine extends JPanel {

    private static final int PANEL_WIDTH = 400;

    public SimpleLine() {
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(PANEL_WIDTH, PANEL_WIDTH));
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g); // so JPanel can do its own housekeeping graphics
        int x1 = 1;
        int y1 = x1;
        int x2 = PANEL_WIDTH - 2;
        int y2 = x2;
        g.drawLine(x1, y1, x2, y2);
    }

    private static void createAndShowGui() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("SimpleLine");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(new SimpleLine());
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> createAndShowGui());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. This works, but it is more advanced than most of anything I've seen. I'm working with the textbook Building Java Programs which introduces graphics before if statements. However it uses a special class (drawing panel) that you have to download, and that kind of takes away the purpose of knowing how to draw with awt, so I'm going to analyze what everything in your code does :)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're working with the textbook [Building Java Programs](http://www.buildingjavaprograms.com). I was able to reproduce your problem, which is not a problem with your code nor with how you have setup Java (assuming you are running Java 8).

Your code is referencing another java class, DrawingPanel, provided by the textbook's author on the author's website.

To continue on your learning path with that textbook, and to get your program to compile, you'll need to download the DrawingPanel class from the textbook website:

http://www.buildingjavaprograms.com/DrawingPanel.java

Then put that java file in the same location as your DrawLine1.java file.

Recompile as you did before, and your code should compile with no errors.

Comment: Thanks! Even though what other people said works, this solves what the book wanted me to do. I was able to compile my code :)